# How to attach an On Click event for Icon In Ext.js

Tags: extjs

I Have an Ext.js Container with an header , header contains a text as its title and an icon . Used to refresh the tab . How can i get icon click event for that container header ?
Ive used  `icon: '@Url.Content("~/Images/icon-supp.png")',` for getting the icon next to the text. 
Here is my code:

'TabChange' also activates only when tab is changed and not while clicked on icon.

More information : I have an center container . Im adding an Ext.tab.Panel to it , which has

```
 items: [ 
            {
                                xtype: 'container',
                                title: 'FooText',
                                id: 'FooPanel',
                                icon: '@Url.Content("~/Images/icon-refresh.png")',
  tools: [{
                        type: 'help',
                        handler: function(){
                            //Doesnt hit on click of tab
                        }
                    }, {
                        itemId: 'refresh',
                        type: 'refresh',
                        hidden: true,
                        handler: function(){
                            //Doesnt hit on click of tab
                        }
                    }
                    }],
                                listeners: {
                                    activate: function () {
                                       //This just hits only once when that tab gets activated./
                                        alert('you clicked me');
                                    },
                                    click:function(){//Doesnt work},
                                        },
                                    handler:function(){//Doesnt work},

                                autoScroll: true,

                            },
```

Now all i need is a handel event on click of image icon. Is it possible ?

Comment: Are you sure is this ExtJS ? or Ext.Net ?

Comment: Can you add more code?

Comment: sorry, are you trying to do a refresh button for the view? version of extjs?

Comment: Yes it is ExtJS which im using. Verision is 4.1.1 and yes i am trying to refresh the contents of that particular tab(there are around 8 tabs in the center container) when click on that icon.

Comment: have you try to use button instead? then you have 'handler'. you can add iconCls or any other class that contain image and not using text.

Comment: Noo.. i cant do that.. convert tabs into buttons ..? Have to change a lot of things in the application + it wont look good . then again il have the same problem.. i want handler for the icon.. not on the whole tab/button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I went on using an html image button on the title and handling the onClick event.As such

```
title: 'fooTitle <input type="image" style="float: right;padding-left:10px; height: 15px;width:30px; " src="Images/icon-refresh.png" onclick="refreshFooTab()"></input>',

function refreshFooTab()
{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is to refresh the tab clicking on an icon, do you know about the tools?

```
tools:
```

An array of Ext.panel.Tool configs/instances to be added to the header tool area. The tools are stored as child components of the header container. They can be accessed using down and {query}, as well as the other component methods. The toggle tool is automatically created if collapsible is set to true.

Note that, apart from the toggle tool which is provided when a panel is collapsible, these tools only provide the visual button. Any required functionality must be provided by adding handlers that implement the necessary behavior.

Example usage:

```
tools:[{
    type:'refresh',
    tooltip: 'Refresh form Data',
    // hidden:true,
    handler: function(event, toolEl, panelHeader) {
        // refresh logic
    }
},
{
    type:'help',
    tooltip: 'Get Help',
    callback: function(panel, tool, event) {
        // show help here
    }
}]
```

obviously using these tools, that already have listeners, you can set css to them and make the tool like as you want.

More informations here:
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-tools

Comment: Its not working.. i dont see any kinda icons even tho i specify - type:'plus'(or something), in Tools

Comment: Ok i used tools for the main panel... and its not what im expecting.. im getting a huge tab kinda thing on my tabs with those icons.. i want a refresh icon inside each of my tabs.

Comment: May be il just use an html input tag and handel the onClick event..><